# How to use the parameter in comparing the variable and constant value?

Tags: verilog

I've learned that using a parameter in defining a module is a good habit like having a default value for the parameter in C++ or other languages.

So, I've used a parameter value a lot but faced a problem when I want to compare some register variable to a constant value that has an equal size with the parameter.

For example, I declare a variable size of which is the value of the parameter and would like to compare it with a constant value sized 8bits such as 8'b0.

```
module top_module #(parameter SIZE = 8) (output out_top);
  reg [(SIZE-1):0] temp_var;
  assign out_top = (temp_var == 8'b0) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
endmodule
```

If I use the constant value with the specific size, in this case, **8'b**, it would be problematic when I want to instantiate the module with the #SIZE = 16 like below.

> top_module #(SIZE=16) top_module_inst;

Is there any way to use the parameter in a declaration of the parameter?

Or should I change the size of the constant value when I instantiate the module with different size every time?

Can anyone please explain the differences between using Hardcoded values and parameters during Synthesis and Simulation?

Answer (score 3):

The verilog replication operator will work here.

The general syntax is: `{n{m}}` (`m` will be replicated `n` times).

The replication count, `n`, must be a constant value, and can be a parameter value.

In your case, the code would be:

```
assign out_top = (temp_var == { SIZE {1'b0} } ) ? 1b'0 : 1'b1;
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Out of curiosity, what happens when we compare the 16bits of data and 8'b0 (8bits of zeros)? Does the 8bits of the constant is zero extended or the expression only compares the Lowest 8bits of the data with the 8bits of the zero?

Comment: There is a whole section in the standard dedicated to this so I can't fully write it here. Basically operator expression are expanded to the biggest of the arguments but the result can sometimes be one bit bigger (e.g. +,- give carry). Within {...} more strict lengths rules apply.